# How to find out the Time complexity for given constraints?

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity, constraints

I have seen in multiple DSA questions like "n=1 or n<= nums.length or n<= 105". So if the constraints are given, then how do I know the exact or estimate time complexity after seeing the constraints? Can someone explain in an easy way?

Comment: Please note that the acronym DSA usually means Digital Signature Algorithm, not "Data Structures and Algorithms".

Comment: The constraints have nothing to do with time complexity. And it is the solution, not the problem, that has a time complexity.

Comment: Of course, the constraints can sometimes give you a hint, such as that there must be a better solution than the simple cubic brute-force solution you just thought of.

Comment: Complexity is related to the implementation of an algorithm, so where is your actual C++ code for us to look at? Also this topic is extensively covered online so do a little research before you ask a low quality question like this. E.g. start here : https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/stor-i-student-sites/lidia-andre/2021/04/27/time-complexity-whats-that/

Answer (score 1):

If the contraints on the size are given then the time complexity is O(1). Non-constant complexity only happens when the input size is variable.